# Evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})(1+\frac{2}{n})^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdots(1+\frac{n}{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdots \left(1+\frac{n}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

solve:
$$ \exp\left\{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\ln(\frac{k}{n}+1)}{\frac{k}{n}}\right\}= \exp\left\{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\,dx\right\}$$

how to evaluate
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\,dx$$

Answer (score 5):

$\dfrac{\ln (1+x)}{x} = 1 -\dfrac{x}{2} + \dfrac{x^2}{3} - \dfrac{x^3}{4} + ....$, thus:

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \dfrac{\ln (1+x)}{x}dx = 1 - \dfrac{1}{2^2} + \dfrac{1}{3^2} - \dfrac{1}{4^2} - ... = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k^2} - 2\cdot \dfrac{1}{2^2}\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k^2} = \dfrac{\pi^2}{12}$

Comment: What is the value of $\sum 1/(k^2)$ cn u please tell

Comment: Its $\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^1\frac{ln(1+x)}{x}dx$$
$$=Li_2(-1)-Li_2(0)$$
$$=-\sum \frac{0}{n^2}+\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$$
$$=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

Comment: I am new to this method. May I know what does $Li$ denote? It seems that it appears frequently in the result of some integrals.

Comment: $Li_n(z)$ is the polylogarithim, defined as $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty  \dfrac{z^k}{k^n}$.

Comment: It appears in integrals involving $\int_{}^{} \dfrac{log(x)}{x}dx$