# How to evaluate $\int_0^1 -\frac {\ln(1-x)}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, summation

This integral came up while I was trying to evaluate $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {1}{n^2}.$$ The value should be $$\frac {\pi^2}{6},$$ but how do I solve the integral and evaluate it?

Comment: @AnginaSeng He's trying to use that to evaluate the sum

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023832/evaluate-lim-n-rightarrow-infty1-frac1n1-frac2n-frac12

Comment: I see, sorry haha

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/621906).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different methods to compute $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$ (Basel problem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2-basel-pro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $t=1-x$ to reexpress the integral as

$$\int_0^1 -\frac {\ln(1-x)}{x}dx
= \int_0^1 \frac {\ln t}{t-1}dt = \frac {\pi^2}6$$

where [$\int_0^1 \frac {\ln x}{x-1}dx = \frac {\pi^2}6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3403819/how-to-integrate-int-01-frac-ln-xx-1dx-without-power-series-expansion/3404200#3404200) is used in the last step

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx= \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k-1}}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}=\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the definition of polylogarithms
$$I(a)=-\int_0^a \frac {\ln(1-x)}{x}dx=\text{Li}_2(a)$$ Expandinga series around $a=1$ gives
$$I(a)=\frac {\pi^2}6-\frac{1}{4} (1-a) (5-a-2 (3-a) \log (1-a))+\cdots$$

If you use this approximation for $a=0.75$, it will give $0.989$ while the exact value is $0.978$.